# Who gets the kills in Apex Legends?

Tags: apex-legends

When you knock down and kill the enemy it's pretty obvious, but there are a few scenarios I don't know and I will exemplify them with 4 teams Alpha, Bravo, Yankee and Zulu. Alpha_N denotes player N from team Alpha

Going on Yankee

- Alpha_1 knocks down Yankee_1
- Bravo_2 kills the knocked down Yankee_1
- Bravo_3 knocks down Yankee_3
- Yankee_3 is not revived / he quits

Going on Zulu

- Bravo_1 knocks down Zulu_1
- Alpha_2 knocks down Zulu_2
- Alpha_3 knocks down Zulu_3 and at this point the Zulu team is eliminated (no self revive available), all Zulu players die.

Who gets what kill here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Apex Legends, the player who knocks down others get kills, but only if knocked down ones are not revived and die successfully, **and** do not quit the game before that.

So:

- Alpha_1 gets one kill with Yankee_1.
- Alpha_2 gets one kill with Zulu_2.
- Alpha_3 gets one kill with Zulu_3.
- Bravo_1 gets one kill with Zulu_1.
- Bravo_3 do not get any kill, even for knocking down Yankee_3. (I feel sorry for him.)

Comment: but `Bravo_3` would get the kill if `Yankee_3` would bleed out and die, correct?

Comment: Whops, yeah, `Bravo_1` gets the kill, not `Alpha_1`. I'll correct that thanks. And for your second comment, yep, that's it.

Comment: I thought the one who actually kills the knock down enemies gets the kill. But this way is fair indeed.

Comment: That's what I thought at beginning too, but I prefer this way (even if it could not seem the more logical). (And don't forget to accept my answer if you think it is ok for you!)

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't quite correct. I knocked down many enemies which have then been killed by other players and I didn't get any kill for them

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Weird, did players which kill these enemies were from your squad?

Comment: Not necessarily. So far I only got the kills into the stats, if the kill tracker in the top right showed that I actually killed/executed the enemy

Comment: If opponents killing your "*knocked down kills*" does not make your kill counter increases, my answer is a bit wrong...